# Dynamically change span text based on selected option javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, innerhtml

I'm trying to change dynamically the text of a span based on the the option that got selected. 
PS: I'm using Django + Python to generate options

Here is my code :

```
<select class="form-control" id="materials">
    {% for material2 in materials %}
        <option value="{{ material2.name }}">{{ material2.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<span id="material_display></span>
```

I've tried :

```
var selected_material = document.getElementById("materials").value;
document.getElementById("material_display").innerTEXT = selected_material
```

But that didn't work out.

Comment: `innerText`, you have a case difference.  Also are you doing this logic as part of a change event handler or something?

Comment: The id on your span is also not closed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `innerText`, not `innerTEXT` and the `id` of your `span` is not closed properly; you only have one quotation mark to the left of the `id` and are missing the quotation mark to the right of the `id`.

You also need to attach your function to an Event Handler like `onchange` for your `select`.

```html
<select id="materials" onchange="showChange()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span id="material_display"></span>
<script>
function showChange(){
var selected_material = document.getElementById("materials").value;
document.getElementById("material_display").innerText = selected_material;
}
</script>
```