# Dynamically update price js or jquery from selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, dynamic

I would like to dynamically update the content of a span supposed to display the price of the selected option.
PS: I'm using Django + Python to generate the options

Here is my code :

```
<select class="form-control" id="materials">
    {% for material2 in materials %}
        <option value="{{ material2.name }}" data-price="{{ material2.price }}">{{ material2.name }} + <span id="material_price">{{ material2.price }}€</span></option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<span id="price_material"></span>
```

This is what I've tried :

```
var material = document.getElementById("materials")
material.onchange = function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("#material_price").value;
    document.getElementById("price_material").innerText = txt
```

Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve this yourself. Remember that SO is here to help you debug code, not to write code for you

Comment: Just updated my code! My bad.

Comment: Wasn't this already addressed?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561897/dynamically-change-span-text-based-on-selected-option-javascript

Comment: Side note, `document.getElementById("#material_price")`  Don't include `#` when using `getElementById`.  That may be your issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you cannot have elements within an `option`, so the `span` needs to be removed.

Your current logic is also reading the `value` from the `select` element. Instead you need to read the `data-price` from the selected `option` element.

You can do that by accessing the `options` array of the `select` to retrieve the element at the `selectedIndex`, then read it's `dataset.price`. Try this:

```js
var priceMaterial = document.getElementById("price_material");

document.getElementById("materials").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  var txt = selected.dataset.price;
  priceMaterial.innerText = txt;
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="materials">
  <option value="name2" data-price="1.99">name2 + 1.99€</option>
  <option value="name3" data-price="10.99">name3 + 10.99€</option>
  <option value="name4" data-price="15.99">name4 + 15.99€</option>
</select>
<span id="price_material"></span>
```

Alternatively, you could do this in jQuery:

```js
var $priceMaterial = $("#price_material");

$("#materials").on('change', function() {
  var txt = $(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
  $priceMaterial.text(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="materials">
  <option value="name2" data-price="1.99">name2 + 1.99€</option>
  <option value="name3" data-price="10.99">name3 + 10.99€</option>
  <option value="name4" data-price="15.99">name4 + 15.99€</option>
</select>
<span id="price_material"></span>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `change` function to watch for changes of the dropdown. Within this function, write code to find the selected option and set the value to the `price_materials` span. You'd be looking at something like the below. See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/kt6ra0uf/17/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#materials').change(function(){
    var value = $('#materials').find(":selected").attr('data-price');
        $('#price_material').text(value);
    });
});
```